# Where is the notification section in my Windows Phone?

Tags: lumia, notifications

In my Nokia Lumia 525 Windows Phone I want to see all my notifications just like in Android OS Phones. If I received a new message in my FB messenger or from other Apps i’m able to see at the top but **I want to see all my notifications in a single place**. I don’t know how to see all those notifications in my Phone. I know in Android OS phone we can see all the notifications my sliding down the top of the screen, but in Windows Phone we don’t have that option. Is there any way to see all my notifications in a single place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Phone have a unique approach: The start screen is your notification center. Without any extra action you will be able to see relevant information from all apps you have pinned. Depending on the size of the tile you chose you may see just the number of messages waiting to be read, or a preview of the messages on larger tiles.

However, this system is going to be extended with a more common iOS/Android style notification center when Windows Phone 8.1 is released in late spring 2014.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing yet as Notification Center like in other major mobile platform (iOS, Android). Microsoft's vision way is to use Live Tiles. They are a key part of the Start screen and the modern experience of Windows. They provide up-to-date content and notifications. Live tiles embody the Microsoft design principle of being fast and fluid. Users can see updates and real-time information from their apps all from their Start Screen, enabling them to quickly review new information and engage with apps even before they open the apps.

However, due to many complaints from users, they are gonna implement a similar concept in their next major update, [Windows Phone 8.1](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2098968/windows-phone-8-1s-long-awaited-notification-center-caught-on-video.html) during April 2014. Hope it will be ok and look nice.